# How can i play mp3/wav with sonic ndk android?

Tags: android

I got working sample for sonic ndk [here](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic-ndk).

It plays talking.bin.When i try to play a mp3 file.It just play noise.Do i need to have seperate decoder for that?Is it possible that i play audio using mediaplayer and somehow change speed (of sound) using sonic?
Any suggestions?

Comment: hey, is your problem solved??? I am also stuck up here with that bin file..

Comment: no that didn't work. So i stopped trying sonic ndk.

Comment: Did you know any other library to work with sound effect like changing pitch and rate.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

The SONIC ndk is playing pcm file.

You can convert any mp3 to pcm and then try that file to play is demo sonic project, you will be able to play the file.For the conversion of mp3 to pcm I used ffmpeg by using command

```
ffmpeg -y -i mymp3file.mp3 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le mypcmfile.pcm
```

Comment: can we convert mp3 to pcm on the go, while running player? How much time it will take to convert?

Comment: Record the audio using AudioTrack class in android and save the file in sdcard, AudioTrack class produces raw PCM file which can be played via the sonic ndk.

Above ffmpeg command will convert mp3 to pcm in 5-6 seconds for 1 minute mp3.
A PCM file simply contains the raw audio without any header information. To convert you need to study a little bit about mp3, and you need to remove some starting bits of data from mp3.

but if you are planning to play this pcm file in android you better go for wav file. you can't play mp3 raw by default in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExtAudioRecorder.java from http://i-liger.com/article/android-wav-audio-recording if you are getting audio from the microphone and it will export your file as a .wav file which can be used but as far as regular music audio in any format, it's a no go.